Go lang tests in local mac
I am trying to run Go lang test of this file https://github.com/istio/istio/blob/release-1.21/tests/integration/security/remote_jwks/remote_jwks_test.go
go test -run TestRemoteJwks remote_jwks_test.go
# command-line-arguments
package command-line-arguments (test)
    imports istio.io/istio/tests/integration/security/util: build constraints exclude all Go files in /Users/mymac/repos/istio/tests/integration/security/util
FAIL    command-line-arguments [setup failed]
FAIL

I just cloned the repo & ran that command, please let me know if I need to run any build or init type of operation to get the tests run in my local
when i run
go test -tags=integ -run TestRemoteJwks

# integration/security/remote_jwks/integration/security/remote_jwks
/Users/mymac/.go/pkg/mod/istio.io/istio@v0.0.0-20241021172555-4dc8332b1b09/pkg/test/framework/config.go:22:2: missing go.sum entry for module providing package github.com/hashicorp/go-multierror (imported by istio.io/istio/pkg/test/framework); to add:
    go get istio.io/istio/pkg/test/framework@v0.0.0-20241021172555-4dc8332b1b09
FAIL    integration/security/remote_jwks/integration/security/remote_jwks [setup failed]

when i try to get that package
go get istio.io/istio/pkg/test/framework@v0.0.0-20241021172555-4dc8332b1b09
go: istio.io/istio/pkg/test/framework imports
    istio.io/istio/pkg/kube imports
    k8s.io/client-go/tools/clientcmd imports
    github.com/imdario/mergo: github.com/imdario/mergo@v1.0.0: parsing go.mod:
    module declares its path as: dario.cat/mergo
            but was required as: github.com/imdario/mergo


As per the docs:

The test framework builds on top of the Go testing infrastructure, and is therefore compatible with the standard go test command-line. For example, to run the tests under the /tests/integration/mycomponent using the default (native) environment, you can simply type:
$ go test -tags=integ ./tests/integration/mycomponent/...
Tests are tagged with the integ build target to avoid accidental invocation. If this is not set, no tests will be run.

If you look in the files you will note the build constraint:
//go:build integ
// +build integ

Because of the constraint the files will only be compiled if integ is set. You are not setting this, so the files are not compiled, hence "build constraints exclude all Go files". To fix this run the test as per the above i.e.:
go test -tags=integ -run TestRemoteJwks


I tried to run but runing to new error updated main description with the errors

Those are quite different issues to the one you originally asked. Run go mod tidy, and see this issue ref mergo (the go.mod contains replace github.com/imdario/mergo => github.com/imdario/mergo v0.3.5).
